# grid-template で余白を設けるときにドットを使うのはそういう仕様ですか？

Tags: html, css

[【HTML/CSSレイアウト】Gridを使うとFlexboxより簡単に複雑なレイアウトを組めます【ヤフー出身エンジニアの初心者向けプログラミング講座】 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwkkD0ejX8Q) で `grid-template` で余白を設けるのにドットを用いています（解説されているように `gap` を使うよりわかりやすそうなので使うつもりです）。

ソースコードは下記のようです。
[html-css-class/style.css at master · lightsound/html-css-class](https://github.com/lightsound/html-css-class/blob/master/002b_%20HolyGrail-grid/style.css)

引用:

```
grid-template:
    "... ...... ...... ...... ...... ...... ..."
    "... header header header header header ..." 150px
    "... ...... ...... ...... ...... ...... ..."
    "... left   ...... center ...... right  ..." 1fr
    "... ...... ...... ...... ...... ...... ..."
    "... footer footer footer footer footer ..." 300px
    "... ...... ...... ...... ...... ...... ..."
    / auto 150px auto 1fr auto 200px auto;
```

このドットについて検索したのですが、仕様のようなものを見つけられませんでした。
ドットでなくても任意の文字列でもいいのでしょうか？　それとも `grid-area` に指定していない名前を表現するためにドットを使う等のグリッドに関する仕様があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid-template-areas` プロパティの値における 1 つ以上のドット (U+002E FULL STOP) は **null セルトークン**を表します<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#grid-template-areas-null-cell-token)</sup>。 Null セルトークンはグリッドコンテナー内の名前のない領域を表しています。

> #### § 7.3. Named Areas: the grid-template-areas property<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#grid-template-areas-null-cell-token)</sup>
>
> - A sequence of one or more "." (U+002E FULL STOP), representing a null cell token.